# How do I use the aws cli to block public access to all of my buckets?

Tags: amazon-s3

I would like the the "Access" column in the web console bucket list to read "not public" for each bucket.

Comment: Turn on S3 Block Public Access for each bucket. See: [Using Amazon S3 block public access - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
for BUCKET_NAME in $(aws s3 --profile YOUR_PROFILE_HERE ls s3:// | cut -d' ' -f3); do aws s3api --profile YOUR_PROFILE_HERE put-public-access-block --bucket "$BUCKET_NAME" --public-access-block-configuration "BlockPublicAcls=true,IgnorePublicAcls=true,BlockPublicPolicy=true,RestrictPublicBuckets=true"; done;
```